# Does inMobi work with appMobi?

Tags: ads, appmobi, inmobi

Does inMobi advertising work with appMobi/xdk apps? I tried putting it in my app the same way as seen here

var inmobi_conf = {
       siteid : "4028cba631d63df10131e1d3191d00cb",
       slot : "15",
       test: true,
       manual: true,
                onError : function(code) {
alert(code);            // do something else. call to other ad network or logic to display in-house ads, etc. 
        }
     };

```
 function loadAdd(){
   _inmobi.getNewAd(document.getElementById('screen'));
```

};

With this in my html

```
  <div style = "background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 0;" id="screen"> </div>
    <button style = "background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 0;" id="btn1" onClick="loadAdd()">Load Ad</button>
```

Every time it will request an ad, turn my div white instead of the red, but show no ad. It will also alert "nfr" meaning no fill response every time. Ive tried in the Intel XDK browser emulator, the Intels Applab app that makes the app run on your device (iPhone), and by actually pushing it and downloading it as an android build. Ive also tried it with both the test ID and an actual ID I registered with my app on the site, neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

InMobi advertising does work with Appmobi/Intel XDK apps. I work for the InMobi Plugins team and we have just released the Appmobi/Intel XDK plugins for InMobi ads. Please refer to the following link for details on integration and the available APIs :

**http://www.inmobi.com/support/art/23837226/22114287/intel-partner-platform-xdk-integration-guide/**

Comment: Im so confused as to where to include the plugin file that I download in that link.
It says to use 
           <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="_appMobi/inmobiplugin.js"></script>

But when you download it it is within a folder and if I put it in say my plugin folder I have no idea where this _appmobi/ directory is to put the code in there

Comment: Please place the inmobiplugin.js present in the plugin zip under the _appMobi subdirectory in the project folder. You have to create the _appMobi subdirectory under your project folder. For further instructions please refer to the link provided earlier. Let us know if you have any other issues.

Comment: Thank you for the continued help, I am still have trouble just getting the page to recognize the plugin. My directory path is as follows:
Desktop\PickMeUp\harrjm.pickmeupv3\4.0.0\retrieve.html
PickMeUp contains all the demos and projects Im working on, as well as a folder called _appMobi, is this where I should put the plugin.
Also do I only need the plugin.js file or all the rest. Sorry for the newb questions I just never use plugins.

Comment: also if I do get it to find the path I get the error
 GET localhost:58888/?CMD=REGISTER_LIBRARY&MODULE=InMobiPluginModule&rnd=97227653

Comment: You have to place only the inmobiplugin.js file present in the plugin zip under the _appMobi folder. Next, please upload the plugin zip bundle when the app is being built using the XDK in the Plugins upload step. The screenshots for the same are shown in this section : http://www.inmobi.com/support/art/23837226/22114287/intel-partner-platform-xdk-integration-guide/#testing-on-a-device.

Comment: Also, regarding your other comment 
"also if I do get it to find the path I get the error GET localhost:58888/?CMD=REGISTER_LIBRARY&MODULE=InMobiPluginModule&rnd=97227653"

Could you explain in more detail about it?